# How can I use match to return characters from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text that is inside of a long string called content.

```
data-seq="0123abcd"
```

Previously I was using the following to match characters but I am not sure if the correct way to do this and it does not work for number of characters that are not eight.

```
var a = content.match(/data-seq="(.{8}).*/)[1]
```

What I need is for the value of `a` to set **all** the characters between the quotes after data-seq and not just eight as in the above.

Comment: But my needs have changed as now I need to get the contents and it could be 3,4 or 8 characters between the quotes. The above I think only works for 8 characters.

Comment: What I need is to get the string of characters between the quotes. data-seq="a", data-seq="12345", data-seq="8888888888" etc. Sorry maybe my post is not clear. I was just giving 3,4 and 8 to show that it could be any number.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read HTML with RegEx which is a bad idea. Are you sure you can't use something like `getAttribute`?

Comment: I am reading the HTML before it goes to the form. I wish I could use getAttribute.

Comment: Why can't you use JavaScript's built-in DOM parsing mechanics? And what "form" are you talking about? Add more details as to what problem you're *acutally* trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would implement it:

```
var a = content.match(/data-seq="([^"]+)"/)[1]
```

This will capture everything between the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = content.match(/data-seq="([^"][a-zA-Z\-0-9]{3,4,8})"/)[1]
```

to match only digits or letters (between quotes), precisely 3,4 or 8 chars.